# Checking for number of shapefiles in directory using Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, shapefile

I want to test:

1. to see whether or not **ONE** AND ONLY ONE shapefile (which will be based on a filename wildcard) exists in a directory.
2. Add these shapefiles to a list
3. Use this list variable as an input to merge_managment function.

I already know how to walk through directories and pick out those filenames but not how to do the above.

I was thinking something like:

```
rootDir = "\homePath"
featureinput1 = "path"
newOnlyShpList = []
for dirPath, dirNames, fileNames in os.walk(rootDir):
    for file in fileNames:
       if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, "*" + "2012" + "*" + ".shp")== True ##AND IF ONE SHAPEFILE EXISTS BY ITSELF IN DIRECTORY:##
          ##append to newOnlyShpList
          arcpy.Merge_managment([featureinput1, newOnlyShpList], "OutputHere")
       elif
          ##ignore if greater than one shapefile
```

All I know about is the arcpy .exists function but all that does is return a boolean on whether any shapefile exists.  Maybe I need to check just for 1 .shp extension and it has nothing to do with arcpy?

Comment: you want to combine all the shapefiles which contain the word 2012 in one ?

Answer (score 7):

Check the glob library:

```
import os
import glob
path = "c:\\my\\dir"

flist = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"shapefile*"))  <- Notice the *

>>> flist 
["c:\\my\\dir\shapefile.prj","c:\\my\\dir\shapefile.shp",...]
```

If you want just the fname without the path attached:

```
 os.path.basename(flist[0]) 
 >>> shapefile.prj
```

if you want just the file name without the extension:

```
os.path.basename(flist[0]).split(".")[0]
>>> shapefile
```

Also if the list is empty, then the file doesn't exist:

```
if flist not:
    print "File not found"
    break #or os.exit(1)
```

Edit: Also to check for the only filename in path :

```
import os
import glob
path = "c:\\my\\dir"

flist = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"shapefile*"))  <- Notice the *
mlist = []
for file in flist:
    if os.path.basename(file).split(".")[0] not in mlist:
        mlist.append(os.path.basename(file).split(".")[0])
if len(mlist)>1: #(More than filename)
    break
```

To check if only one shapefile in the dir:

```
 def file_check(path):
      """Returns true if in path there is only one basename"""
      import os
      mlist = [] 
      for file in os.listdir(path):
          if os.path.basename(file).split(".")[0] not in mlist:
                mlist.append(os.path.basename(file).split(".")[0]
   if len(mlist)>1:
            return True
    else:
            return False
```

Comment: What is the difference between glob and fnmatch that i was using? Also being new to python when you add [0] after split what is that referring to?

Comment: And i need to join dirPath and file since I am using os.walk in rootDir.  Otherwise it doesnt have the filepath to merge once the shapefile in the directory by itself is found.

Comment: glob returns a list we can play with. fnmatch as far as i know returns a boolean T/F value. Split, splits the string using the designated character. eg "this.is.true".split(".") will produce this list : ['this', 'is', 'true']. To select an element from the list you just designate which one you want starting from 0. So .split(".")[0] just says : " split the string at dots, and give me back the first occurrence" . You can find more info here http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/lists.html

Comment: It's easy to joir dirPath and File in a single path once you have a list with the file names and the path: eg: for x in [x+".shp" for x in mlist]:print os.path.join(path,x)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Havent had any luck so far, but one other thing.  You use the glob.glob in the variable flist, but I don't see where flist is associated with anything else in the code.

Comment: yes you're right. I misnamed my variables. And thats how bugs are born!

Answer (score 6):

ArcGIS has a built in function to list all shapefiles in a folder:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env    

arcpy.env.workspace = 'E:/myFolder/'
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp", "")
```

`fcs` is an array that stores the name of all of the shapefiles in the folder `myFolder`. For example, to print out all of the shapefiles in `myFolder` you can just do this:

```
for shp in fcs:    
    print shp
```

[just moving this from the comment] 
To test if the list of files contains only the file that you want in this folder, you could use the condition:

```
if 'myfile' in fcs and len(fcs)==1:
       print 'true'
```

Comment: Aware of this, but doesnt really help when you have to walk through a number of directories and pick out those shapfiles that are by themselves in a directory.  And then throw them in a new list.   I appreciate user528025 ideas, but it so different from what I began with that I am having a hard time grasping it and getting anything to work.  I guess that is what I get for trying to do something above my python level.

Comment: you can still walk through all the folders as you are doing, and just use `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp", "")` in each folder. To see if the filelist contains only that file you could use the condition `if 'myfile' in fcs and len(fcs)==1:`...

Comment: Alright I will give it a try when I have arcpy module available to me.  And probably get back to you for help later =D

Answer (score -1):

To answer this question nowadays (since ArcGIS 10.1 SP1) I would recommend the [answer from @djq](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30071) in conjunction with using [arcpy.da.Walk](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) to walk the folder structure:

> Generate data names in a directory/database structure by walking the
>   tree top-down or bottom-up. Each directory/workspace yields a tuple of
>   three: directory path, directory names, and file names.